# Problem while using fluentvalidation to validate a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, fluentvalidation

i am a newbie to WPF and i am struggling to validate a DataGrid by using FluentValidation 
what i am trying to to is validating every row in Datagrid
the problem is some rows even though they're valide it shows that they are not valid

here is a screenshot of the strange behavior of DataGrid

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xXQR.png)

here is the code that i am using

- class

  ```
  public class DetailFacture : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo , IEditableObject
  {
  private DetailFactureValidator _detailFactureValidator;

  private string _libellePiece;
  private decimal _montantHT;
  private decimal _tauxTVA;
  private string _compteCharge;
  private string _compteTva;
  private string _codeTva;

  public DetailFacture ( )
  {
      _detailFactureValidator = new DetailFactureValidator( );
  }

  public string LibellePiece
  {
      get { return _libellePiece; }
      set
      {
          _libellePiece = value;
          OnPropertyChanged( "LibellePiece" );
      }
  }

  public decimal MontantHT
  {
      get { return _montantHT; }
      set
      {
          _montantHT = value;
          OnPropertyChanged( "MontantHT" );
      }
  }

  public decimal TauxTVA
  {
      get { return _tauxTVA; }
      set
      {
          _tauxTVA = value;
          OnPropertyChanged( "TauxTVA" );
      }
  }

  public string CompteCharge
  {
      get { return _compteCharge; }
      set
      {
          _compteCharge = value;
          OnPropertyChanged( "CompteCharge" );
      }
  }

  public string CompteTva
  {
      get { return _compteTva; }
      set
      {
          _compteTva = value;
          OnPropertyChanged( "CompteTva" );
      }
  }

  public string CodeTva
  {
      get { return _codeTva; }
      set
      {
          _codeTva = value;
          OnPropertyChanged( "CodeTva" );
      }
  }

  public string Error
  {
      get
      {
          if ( _detailFactureValidator != null )
          {
              var results = _detailFactureValidator.Validate( this );
              if ( results != null && results.Errors.Any( ) )
              {
                  var errors = string.Join( Environment.NewLine , results.Errors.Select( x => x.ErrorMessage ).ToArray( ) );
                  return errors;
              }
          }
          return string.Empty;
      }
  }

  public string this[ string columnName ]
  {
      get
      {
          var firstOrDefault = _detailFactureValidator.Validate( this ).Errors.FirstOrDefault( lol => lol.PropertyName == columnName );
          if ( firstOrDefault != null )
              return _detailFactureValidator != null ? firstOrDefault.ErrorMessage : "";
          return "";
      }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ( string propertyName )
  {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
  }

  private DetailFacture backupCopy;
  private bool inEdit;

  public void BeginEdit ( )
  {
      if ( inEdit )
          return;
      inEdit = true;
      backupCopy = this.MemberwiseClone( ) as DetailFacture;
  }

  public void CancelEdit ( )
  {
      if ( !inEdit )
          return;
      inEdit = false;
      this.CodeTva = backupCopy.CodeTva;
      this.CompteCharge = backupCopy.CompteCharge;
      this.CompteTva = backupCopy.CompteTva;
      this.LibellePiece = backupCopy.LibellePiece;
      this.MontantHT = backupCopy.MontantHT;
      this.TauxTVA = backupCopy.TauxTVA;
  }

  public void EndEdit ( )
  {
      if ( !inEdit )
          return;
      inEdit = false;
      backupCopy = null;
  }
  }
  ```
- Validator

  ```
  public class DetailFactureValidator : AbstractValidator<DetailFacture>
  {
  public DetailFactureValidator ( )
  {
      RuleFor( det => det.CodeTva ).NotNull( ).WithMessage( "CodeTva ne doit pas être vide" )
          .ExclusiveBetween("32" , "44").WithMessage("Code Tva doit etre entre 32 et 44")
          .Matches( @"\w*" ).WithMessage( "CodeTva n'est pas une chaîne de caractères" );

      RuleFor( det => det.CompteCharge ).NotNull( ).WithMessage( "CompteCharge ne doit pas être      vide" )
          .Matches( @"\w*" ).WithMessage( "CompteCharge n'est pas une chaîne de caractères" );

      RuleFor( det => det.CompteTva ).NotNull( ).WithMessage( "CompteTva ne doit pas être vide" )
          .Matches( @"\w*" ).WithMessage( "CompteTva n'est pas une chaîne de caractères" );

      RuleFor( det => det.LibellePiece ).NotNull( ).WithMessage( "LibellePiece ne doit pas être vide" )
          .Matches( @"\w*" ).WithMessage( "LibellePiece n'est pas une chaîne de caractères" );

  }
  }
  ```
- Xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="errorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
           <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-2"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                   <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
         Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
           Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
               </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
           <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
           <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
           <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
           <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
       </Style>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
           <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                       <Image Source="/Images/Alerte.png" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={ RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" Margin="0" Width="11" Height="11" />
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
       </Style>
   </UserControl.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="grille" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding FactureDetailList, Mode=TwoWay ,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FF06C257" BorderBrush="#FF02401D" Foreground="#FF929292" BorderThickness="0" CanUserResizeColumns="False" >
                           <DataGrid.Columns>
                               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Libelle Piece" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" Binding="{Binding LibellePiece, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Montant HT" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" Binding="{Binding MontantHT, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Taux TVA" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" Binding="{Binding TauxTVA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />

                               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compte Charge" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" Binding="{Binding CompteCharge, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Compte Tva" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" Binding="{Binding CompteTva, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code Tva" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" Binding="{Binding CodeTva, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                           </DataGrid.Columns>
                       </DataGrid>
```

- Xaml.cs

```
 public partial class FormulaireUC : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DetailFacture> FactureDetailList;
        public FormulaireUC ( )
        {
            InitializeComponent( );

            grille.ItemsSource = FactureDetailList;
        }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you try to break the issue into 2 separate ones. First, ensure the rules are working as you want in a separate test console application. Second, check the data grid values received by your code at run time. Maybe the binding is wrong or the new entered data is not reaching the variables you expect.

Comment: thanks for your answer , I solved the problem by adding this line to my XAML code 
` <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
   <DataErrorValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"></DataErrorValidationRule>
  </DataGrid.RowValidationRules> `

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It would be nice to put your comment above (showing how you solved the problem) as an answer. This will let people know how you solved the problem and will mark the question as "answered".